# I need to redirect the user to this one page in case of ANY kind of error

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I added this in my webconfig file but its not redirecting. It shows the aspx error as it is with the Stack Trace and all:-

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="myhomepage.aspx"/>
```

What could be wrong? Please help me out.

Comment: Have you put it in <system.web>?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the values as `mode="On"` so that it shows up the custom errors. This will allow custom errors for remote clients as well as localhost (while you debug) and it is not the case for `RemoteOnly` which ignores the localhost.

More details [refer here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The way you've got it set up at the moment is that it will show that page for any users that are not on the same computer that IIS is running on. If you're testing it from localhost then it won't work (unless as V4Vendetta suggested you set the Mode to On).

Answer (score 0):

RemoteOnly means.. Remote Only.  In other words, you see the YSOD (Yellow Screen Of Death) when you view the page with the error if you are browsing from the same computer as the program is executing on.

If you view it from a different computer, then you will see your custom error page.

If you want to see the custom error even when browsing locally, then use mode="On".

If you are still not seeing the custom error message, even if browsing remotely, it probably means you did not add it to the correct section of the web.config.  It should be in

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="myhomepage.aspx"/> 
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```